# Add each last occurence of object to list ordered by most recent addition

Tags: c#, performance, logging

I need a logger of sorts and have to dump the contents from time to time.
I want to get only the last instance of each item and preserve that order.

Is there a better way to do it than like this? List.contains is to expensive, but I'm not happy with the memory overhead of the extra hashset aswell.

```
 public List<Int3> UnsafeDumpMostRecentUsageLast() {

        HashSet<Int3> _containsHelper = new HashSet<Int3>();
        List<Int3> uniqueOccurencesOrdered = new List<Int3>(uniqueConsumedCount);

        for (int i = usageLog.Length-1;i >= 0; i--) {

            if (_containsHelper.Add(usageLog[i])) 
                uniqueOccurencesOrdered.Add(usageLog[i]);

        }
        uniqueOccurencesOrdered.Reverse();
        return uniqueOccurencesOrdered;
    }
```

To clear it up.. say I have a list like this:

aabbbaabbbccabccccdeddaccc

I want to return a list that returns the uppercases:

aabbbaabbbccaBccccdEdDAccC

So the list would be: BEDAC

Not:
AaBbbaabbbCcabccccDEddaccc

ABCDE

Comment: *List.contains is to expensive, but I'm not happy with the memory overhead of the extra hashset aswell.* Then you might consider [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), for instance from [here](https://bloomfilter.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Is this the primary use for usageLog? Could you consider a data structure that inserts and tracks the latest used as it is inserted?

Comment: @JasonHernandez I use it to keep track of what Data I can dump from the RAM buffer of a custom DB.I tried a linkedlist where I always removed the node of a requestToken and added it back last. But that action obviously causes problems with concurrent requests.  I now use a overflow array to track of most recent users and a 2d hashed array to store all requests. For this usecase I don't need any locks or Interlocked methods. The dump method in my OP happens in a writerlock that I need anyway because it managed acces to the primary HD storage.

Comment: So you were keeping a linked list, and moving the MRU to the head of the list. But that fell apart in concurrent scenarios. To avoid the concurrency issues you moved the code to the dump, to post process it, so to speak. Am I getting this right?

Comment: also, how big is your usageLog and how many distinct values  do you have? I'm guessing more that 4 or 5 since  you are worried about List.contains performance

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what `Int3` type is, but if we assume we are talking about an int (works similarly in other cases) and `usageLog` is an `IEnumerable`you could do the following:

```
public List<Int3> UnsafeDumpMostRecentUsageLast() {          
    return usageLog.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

**Addition**

If your list is already sorted and you just want to keep the last occurrence of each instance (like your comment suggests) :

`usageLog.Reverse().Distinct().Reverse().ToList();`

Comment: That would give me the wrong order. I updated my OP with an example... Would 'return usageLog.Reverse().Distinct().Reverse().ToList();' Do what I want?

Comment: @user3488765 Updated answer

Comment: Wow, and this is considered to be more performant then the original implementation - internal hash set for `Distiinct` + additional buffer for `Reverse` + additional list from `ToList`. Just ridiculous. Better remove `performance` tag.

Comment: @IvanStoev I removed the accept answer. After Rob posted the same as SteelSoul and I saw his reputation I didn't do any more research into the answers as I thought they'd know better If they bothered to leave a reply. Do you by any chance know a better method than my original?

Comment: Actually no :) I think it's optimal. The only potential improvement I see is replacing the `HashSet` with some custom lightweight equivalent, mainly to avoid reallocations, due to the lack of a way to specify the capacity of the hash set in advance.

Comment: @IvanStoev Do you think that is worse? Not according to my benchmarks. If you have some other numbers I'd like to see them. Also, constructive ideas will be appreciated rather than "Just ridiculous".

Comment: I don't see any benchmarks. The 2 LINQ Reverse calls are obviously inefficient, especially the second as well as the last `ToList`. I have nothing against LINQ, I'm using it a lot, but only where appropriate. If the question was for concise code, readability, maintainability - I'm just fine with your solution. But the tag is performance and also memory overheads, so suggesting LINQ is, hmm, you already know what :) A general principle - avoid LINQ in time/space critical code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var str = "aabbbaabbbccabccccdeddaccc";
var result = new string(str
    .Reverse()
    .Distinct()
    .Reverse()
    .ToArray()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hash based lookup gives you the best time complexity (hence performance). If you are not satisfied with `HashSet` class space overhead (and additional costs of extending the internal storage and rehashing), it's not hard to create your own hash structure specific for the operation needed.

For instance, the following algorithm uses 2 `int` arrays of size `N` to achieve the same goal with much less overhead. The first array called `head` serves the hash table buckets linked lists start index while `next` holds the index of the next entry in the bucket, and also is used to identify the last unique entries. There is no need to store the values because we already have them, and the whole mapping is by index.

```
static List<T> UnsafeDumpMostRecentUsageLast<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> source, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    var head = new int[source.Count];
    var next = new int[source.Count];
    int count = 0;
    if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = source[i];
        // Check for duplicate
        int bucket = (comparer.GetHashCode(item) & int.MaxValue) % head.Length;
        int prev = -1, last = head[bucket] - 1;
        while (last >= 0 && !comparer.Equals(source[last], item))
            last = next[prev = last];
        if (last >= 0)
        {
            // Found, replace it in the hash chain (we need only the last) 
            next[i] = next[last];
            if (prev >= 0)
                next[prev] = i;
            else
                head[bucket] = i + 1;
            // Use int.MinValue (value < -1) to mark the duplicate entry as not being last
            next[last] = int.MinValue;
        }
        else
        {
            next[i] = head[bucket];
            head[bucket] = i + 1;
            count++;
        }
    }
    var result = new List<T>(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < next.Length; i++)
    {
        if (next[i] < -1) continue;
        result.Add(source[i]);
        if (result.Count == count) break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is the usage in your case:

```
public List<Int3> UnsafeDumpMostRecentUsageLast()
{
    return UnsafeDumpMostRecentUsageLast(usageLog);
}
```

and a test:

```
var source = "aabbbaabbbccabccccdeddaccc".ToCharArray();
var result = UnsafeDumpMostRecentUsageLast(source);
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(result));
// output: bedac
```